# Is a linear transformation solely determined by a particular set of bases and an associated matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Let be $T:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$, the basis $B=\{(1,-1,1),(1,1,1),(1,0,0)\}$ and $A=\{(1,2,0),(2,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$ and the following matrix the transformation matrix on those basis:\begin{bmatrix}
>         -1 & -2 & -5 \\
>         0 & 2 & 2 \\
>         2 & 2 & 4 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
>   Is T solely determined by that matrix? Why?

I think it is, but I'm having trouble with the 'because' part. Any help will we appreciated.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) for some info on similar matrices, which are matrices representing the same linear transformation under different bases. Maybe look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence) too.

Comment: Write an arbitrary vector as a linear combination of basis elements. Using linearity, is the image uniquely determined by the images of the basis elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that:

- $T(1,-1,1)=-1\times(1,2,0)+0\times(2,1,0)+2\times(1,1,1)=(-4,0,4)$;
- $T(1,1,1)=-2\times(1,2,0)+2\times(2,1,0)+2\times(1,1,1)=(-8,4,8)$;
- $T(1,0,0)=-5\times(1,2,0)+2\times(2,1,0)+4\times(1,1,1)=(-1,0,2)$.

And then, since $B$ is a basis and you know the image by $T$ of every element of $B$, you know $T(x,y,z)$ for every $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$: you express $(x,y,z)$ as $\alpha(1,-1,1)+\beta(1,1,1)+\gamma(1,0,0)$ and then$$T(x,y,z)=\alpha(-4,0,4)+\beta(-8,4,8)+\gamma(-1,0,0),$$since $T$ is linear.